# how to retrieve json data in sequence

Tags: php, json

i have simple json results like below

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "image": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
  "result": [
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/1",
      "label": "MP4"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/2",
      "label": "FLV"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/3",
      "label": "MP3"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/4",
      "label": "AVI"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://example.com/5",
      "label": "WMV"
    }
  ]
}
```

as you can see, that there are so many different label paths, and sometimes the sequence of labels is not like the above, it's always changing (random), and I'm trying to get the MP3 label part but can not.
My question is, how to take the sequence of json which has MP3 label?

I have tried with the script below

```
$uri = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://example.com/json.json'),TRUE);
echo $uri['result'][2]['url'];
```

but as described above, the position of the MP3 label is always changing, is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: Iterate over `result` and check `label` value.

Comment: a simple foreach and an if statement should suffice

Comment: thanks ghost, its work

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

```
$nodesWithMp3Labels = array_map(function($a) {
    if (strtolower($a["label"]) == "mp3") {
        return $a;
    }
}, $uri['result']);
```

Read more about [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
With `array_map`, there will be some blank values if label is not mp3.

Another solution using simple foreach loop:

```
$nodesWithMp3Labels = [];

foreach ($uri['result'] as $a) {
    if (strtolower($a["label"]) == "mp3") {
        $nodesWithMp3Labels[] = $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you will receive array with null values where `label` is __not__ 'mp3'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `array_filter` to get all the results with MP3 label:

```
$uri = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://example.com/json.json'), true);

$mp3 = array_filter($uri['result'], function($item) {
    return $item['label'] === 'MP3';
})
```